# Offline JSON diff tool

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, json

I am looking for a similar tool like [JSON diff tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25018/diff-tool-for-json-files) but with the additional requirement that the tool works offline. I am asking a new question, because many answers over there do also not fit the requirements requested by OP.

I need:

- gratis, free of cost, open source preferred. And I mean really gratis forever, not a 30 day trial version. Also gratis for commercial use.
- Windows 10 and 11
- offline. My data must not be sent to the Internet.
- compares JSON with JSON in mind, i.e.

  - order of key/value pairs is irrelevant
  - whitespace outside of values is irrelevant
  - order of arrays is relevant
- Either displays the difference directly (program has a GUI) or mangles the two JSON files in a way that a standard Difftool can compare it.

Comment: linux has system "diff" command.  I believe it is in all linux distros. It is offline no internet. I see you want windows but perhaps you can get access to "diff" through the linux in windows.

Comment: @tckosvic: and you think the Linux diff tool will consider the sorting of JSON?

Comment: Not a proper tool, but I was using JSONedit to reformat files, setting JSON elements order to alphabetical and text formatting to "styled" in settings to "normalize" JSON (same can be done with just json-cpp that is underneath) and then just a regular text diff.

Comment: @TMSZ: I think it qualifies as "mangles the two JSON files in a way that a standard Difftool can compare it.". It's a bit sad that it doesn't have Unicode support yet.

Comment: Unicode would not matter in this case, but I would suggest some DIY that would make it more convenient: small application that accepts two files through drag-and-drop, normalizes JSON (e.g. using json-cpp) creating two temporary files and launches some diff tool (WinMerge maybe?) passing temporary file names to it.